# wpf toolkit (Feb 2010) datagrid with MVVM - style reveals name of view model on 'spare column'

Tags: wpf, styles, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I've just updated my app with the latest WPF toolkit and I've now got an issue with my styling.

When I bind some data with, for example, two columns to the grid, the header in the spare area at the right shows the name of the ViewModel.

So if I bind an IEnumerable with two columns the Grid Header looks like

Column1, Column1, [Namespace].MyViewModel

Before the Feb 2010 update it just used to have Column1, Column2 - the final space being blank.

I can kind of understand why, because the data grids data context is the ViewModel, whereas the Columns seem to have a different DataContext ... but I can't work out how I'm supposed to fix it.

I'm defining my header style as follows ...

....

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGridHeaderBorder
    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="4,0,4,0" />
    </Border>
</WpfToolkit:DataGridHeaderBorder>
```

....

Do I now need a separate style for the 'spare column' or something?

Can anyone assist please?

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to move to a Telerik grid to get the group functionality, so never solved the problem as it stood.  It was probably something in the mass of styles the program had accumulated!

Answer (score 1):

In the textblock (`<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="4,0,4,0" />`) you are binding directly to the ViewModel, which is an object. As fallback, `object.ToString()` is used while Binding, which is the name of the ViewModel. You have to specify a path ie. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="4,0,4,0" />` to bind to.

Comment: But doing that would mean that the column headers that have a data context of an actual value would not work.

Comment: Just don't bind the text then?

Comment: Sorry I probably havnt been clear, I don't want the binding to apply to the 'spare column' - only the other columns, i don't know whether its a different type or something?  It used to be fine before the Feb 2010 update.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help - i've added some more info to the question.